# how to set and dismiss SVProgressHUD when move to another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, svprogresshud

I want to show progress bar when press a button to move another `ViewController` (This `ViewController` is load with huge amount of data from the WebService) and after load all data progress bar will be dismiss.

I mean first press a button then immediately move to another `ViewController` with progress bar and progress bar dismiss after load all data.

here I add the code for move to another `ViewController`:

```
UIStoryboard *sb=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
Guide *guideVC = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Guide"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:guideVC animated:YES];
```

And WebService simply fetch in `viewDidLoad` method on new `ViewController`.

How can I do this. Any one give the solution.

Comment: You should use operation queue for handle this

Comment: Could you Please show your code ?

Comment: how give me an example pls @Tofaani Kaanudo

Comment: wait i will update the code @Dixit Akabari

Comment: Why don't you call the Webservice after you open another viewcontroller(in `viewDidLoad`) ?. It will make your task easier

Comment: yes i call the Webservice after open another viewcontroller(in viewDidLoad) but when I press the button it will take time to move new viewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

> Here i have just show you how to dissmiss SVProgress Here i have used my own APIManager(Using Alamofire) Custom class for Api calling

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.fetchList()
    }
    func fetchList() {
        SVProgressHUD.show()
        APIManager.callAPIRequest(Method: .post, url: urlStr, parameters: parameters, headers: headers, completion:
            { (result, headerMessage) in
                let dicJSONResponse = result.dictionaryValue
                //SuccessBlock
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }) { (httpresponse, errorMessage) in
            //Failure blog
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }
    }
```

Comment: welcome, if its really help you than please mark as answer @MUNNA

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following:

1. I think you are using a basewebservice(parent class) for all your
   webservice task.
2. Start the progress bar before the webservice call(call GET, POST,
   PUT and PATCH).
3. Stop the progress bar after getting success or failure callbacks.
4. If you have to process very large data, please run it in the
   background thread for the smooth working of UI thread.

Comment: can you please give me an example

Comment: for better understanding